# Best practice of social login with separate FrontEnd and BackEnd

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I create an application with the following architecture :

- Backend : Spring Boot 3.0.0 (with Spring Security)
- Frontend : Angular 15
- DataBase : Mysql

The Backend and Frontend are 2 separated projects. I try to use social login with Google and Facebook, I finally understand how this work using JWT and interceptors in the Frontend.

My question is what is the best practice to use social login, do we call Google login from Angular using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@abacritt/angularx-social-login) in addition use necessary dependencies on pom.xml, or we don't mention any thing about Google login in the frontend and we just call it in the backEnd with the necessary dependencies in pom.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to use your backend. Here you can manage token more secure and if you use authorization, too, you need the secure token data from google in your backend, too. [Here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth?hl=de) is a link to official Google documentation.

Spring, so you use JAVA. This can be what you need (from the Google docu):

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdToken;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdToken.Payload;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdTokenVerifier;

...

GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(transport, jsonFactory)
    // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend:
    .setAudience(Collections.singletonList(CLIENT_ID))
    // Or, if multiple clients access the backend:
    //.setAudience(Arrays.asList(CLIENT_ID_1, CLIENT_ID_2, CLIENT_ID_3))
    .build();

// (Receive idTokenString by HTTPS POST)

GoogleIdToken idToken = verifier.verify(idTokenString);
if (idToken != null) {
  Payload payload = idToken.getPayload();

  // Print user identifier
  String userId = payload.getSubject();
  System.out.println("User ID: " + userId);

  // Get profile information from payload
  String email = payload.getEmail();
  boolean emailVerified = Boolean.valueOf(payload.getEmailVerified());
  String name = (String) payload.get("name");
  String pictureUrl = (String) payload.get("picture");
  String locale = (String) payload.get("locale");
  String familyName = (String) payload.get("family_name");
  String givenName = (String) payload.get("given_name");

  // Use or store profile information
  // ...

} else {
  System.out.println("Invalid ID token.");
}
```

Comment: Yes that make sense, I have seen many confusing tutorial that call Google login from Angular project and then manage the token in the backend.

Comment: Yes, but the better way is to go with the backend. Here you need the data, too and the backend is the better place for API Keys and so on.

Comment: In fact I am a little bit comfused, because even when the call of Google login from the frontEnd they manage the token and every thing in backend, so the sequence diagram is similar in both cases : (1) call and manage google login only from backend, (2) call Google login from Angular and managed it from backand.

Comment: Ok. If you authenticated your backend can do authorize you. So give you access to special routes or not. Or can handle what to do if the token expired and so on.

Comment: Yes the backend manage all those things, just the first call of the authentication page is done From frentend using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@abacritt/angularx-social-login). Is that can be okey?

Comment: Yes. Sure. OAuth and so on using this way.